# Use JQuery Ajax to update the number of likes on a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im using the following code in my HTML. It tries to update the number of likes and dislikes for each review when a user clicks on it. This is the jquery part of it.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#likes").click(function(){
  $updateLikes();
 });
$("#dislikes").click(function(){
$updateDislikes();
});

function rate(){ //'rating' VARIABLE FROM THE FORM in view.php
var the_id = $("#id").val(); //'id' OF THE CONTENT BEING RATED
var data = 'noLikes='+$noLikes+'&id='+the_id;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'rate.php', //POSTS FORM TO THIS FILE
    data: data,
    success: function(e){
        $("#id").html(e); //REPLACES THE TEXT OF view.php
        }
    });
}

function rate(){
    var the_id = $("#id").val(); //'id' OF THE CONTENT BEING RATED
var data = 'noDislikes='+$noDisikes+'&id='+the_id;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'dislikes.php', //POSTS FORM TO THIS FILE
    data: data,
    success: function(e){
        $("#id").html(e); //REPLACES THE TEXT OF view.php
        }
    });
}
```

});

And the html section is here:

```
 $getreviewresults = $mysqli->query("SELECT companyReviewed, reviewID, majorName, gpa,
 noLikes, noDislikes, dayAtWork FROM reviews NATURAL JOIN usersPosted NATURAL JOIN users 
 NATURAL JOIN majorOfUser NATURAL JOIN majors");
 <table class="table-ReviewResults">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" class="viewReviewLink"><a href="review.php">View Review</a>     </td>
        <td class="schoolInfo">
    <?php
        print('COMPANY:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="resultData">'.$reviewitem['companyReviewed'].'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        print('MAJOR:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="resultData">'.$reviewitem['majorName'].'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
        print('GPA RANGE:&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="resultData">'.$reviewitem['gpa'].'</span>');
    ?>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" class="reviewRatingsNumbers">
    <?php
        $q = $mysqli->query("SELECT noLikes FROM reviews WHERE id='".$reviewitem['reviewID']);
        $likes['reviewID'] = $mysqli->num_rows($q);
        $p = $mysqli->query("SELECT noDislikes FROM reviews WHERE id='".$reviewitem['reviewID']);
        $dislikes['reviewID'] = $mysqli->num_rows($p);

        $l = 'likes';
        $d = 'dislikes';
        if($likes==1){
            $l = 'like';
        }
        if($dislikes==1){
            $d = 'dislike';
        }

        //THE NUMBER OF LIKES & DISLIKES
        print('<img id="likes'.$reviewitem['reviewID'].'" onClick="rate($(this).attr(\'id\'))" src="images/rateReview2-up.jpg">
            <img id="dislikes'.$reviewitem['reviewID'].'" onClick="rate($(this).attr(\'id\'))" src="images/rateReview2-down.jpg"><br />');
        print($likes.' '.$l.' and '.$dislikes.' '.$d);
```

I am not sure how to create the likes.php and dislikes.php files that would update the number of likes and dislikes and send them to the current page using AJAX so they can be updated. Plus, Im not sure if the way Im going about it is right as I havent used JQuery before. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The likes.php and dislikes.php files can be as simple as the following:

```
<?php
    $clickedId = $_POST["id"];

    $numberOfLikes = updateLikes($clickedId);

    echo $numberOfLikes;


    function updateLikes($id)
    {
        // run UPDATE likes query

        // run SELECT numberOfLikes query

        return $numberOfLikes;
    }
?>
```

The success portion of the AJAX function would receive the `numberOfLikes` variable echoed from the PHP and, based on your code, place it in the HTML of the element with `id="id"`.

Note, though, that your jQuery doesn't match your HTML in the code you posted.

In the HTML, you've got images with ids of `likes` and `dislikes` with each being appended with the ID of the item being rated.  This is good, as element ids must be unique.

Based on these links, though, you'll want to add a class to each image to make it easier to set up the click events.

let's say that one pair of like/dislike images ends up like this:

```
<img id="likes17" 
     class="rate-like"
     src="images/rateReview2-up.jpg">

<img id="dislikes17" 
     class="rate-dislike"
     src="images/rateReview2-down.jpg">
```

[formatting for clarity]

This would change the setup of your click event for the like images to the following:

```
$(".rate-like").click(function() {
    var elementId = $(this).attr('id');  // would be 'likes17' based on image above
    var clickedItemId = elementId.replace('likes', '');
    updateLikes(clickedItemId);
});
```

And the updateLikes function would look something like this:

```
function updateLikes(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'likes.php',
        data: 'id=' + id,
        success: function(data){
            $('#likes' + id).html(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errorMessage = xhr.responseText;
            errorMessage = errorMessage.substring(errorMessage.indexOf('<title>') + 7, errorMessage.indexOf('</title>'));
            alert('Unable to update likes: ' + errorMessage);
        }
    });
}
```

Hopefully, this all makes sense to you, but feel free to post any questions you may have in the comments for this answer.

Comment: Thanks. You explained it really well, and I thought I understood it. but the onClick event doesnt work at all. nothing happens when i click it. What could be wrong with it? Is there a way I could send the new code to you!?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to have the number of likes, dislikes, and the review ID accessible within the DOM.  Something like this for example:

```
Likes: <span id='likes_count'>$likes</span>
Dislikes: <span id='dislikes_count'>$dislikes</span>
<span style='display: none;' id='review_id'>$reviewitem['reviewID']</span>
```

Now when you make the AJAX call it's possible to reference these values.

```
$("#likes").click(function(){
    $.post('updateLikes.php?reviewid=' + $("#review_id").text(), function() {
        // TODO check whether successful
        // increment # of likes and display
        var current_likes = parseInt($("#likes_count").text());
        $("#likes_count").text(current_likes++);
    });
});
```

(And the same for dislikes.)  The final step is to implement "updateLikes.php", which should basically just run a SQL update and return success/failure.

```
$q = $mysqli->query("UPDATE reviews SET noLikes = noLikes + 1 WHERE id=".$_GET['reviewid']);
// TODO return indication of success/failure
```